# Use Ecto.Multi to update a table twice in the same transaction

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Consider a scenario where you are trying to model the logging of a bank transaction. A transaction has an amount, a type (credit or debit,) and is associated with an account.

In the case of adding a new bank transaction, I can do this, and it works well:

```
Multi.new()
|> Multi.insert(:transaction, transaction_changeset)
|> Multi.update(:account, account_changeset)
|> Repo.transaction()
```

Updating an existing bank transaction is a little more involved. That's because a user can not only change the amount, but also the account. Updating an existing transaction could mean removing the amount from the previous account, in addition to adding the amount to the current account. I tried this, but I'm not sure how to express what I'm trying to do using `Ecto.Multi`.

```
Multi.new()
|> Multi.update(:transaction, transaction_changeset)
|> Multi.update(:account, previous_account_changeset)
|> Multi.update(:account, current_account_changeset)
|> Repo.transaction()
```

> Runtime error :account is already a member of the Ecto.Multi:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The issue here is that you are using the `:account` key twice.** From the [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html):

> `Ecto.Multi` makes it possible to pack operations that should be performed in a single database transaction and gives a way to introspect the queued operations without actually performing them. Each operation is given a name that is unique and will identify its result in case of success or failure.

---

**You can choose whatever name you like as long as it's unique.** Simply change your transaction to something like:

```elixir
Multi.new
|> Multi.update(:transaction, transaction_changeset)
|> Multi.update(:previous_account, previous_account_changeset)
|> Multi.update(:current_account, current_account_changeset)
|> Repo.transaction
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. I was under the false impression that the key needed to be the schema name. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Doesn't even have to be an atom by the way. It can just be a string. If you, like me, are just iterating over a set of records and reduce those as changesets onto a multi, you can just use the ID field as a name for the update. (UUID string in my case)